# Operations: how to filter text messages on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

Question for operations people. I work at a place that believes in configuring Nagios to send SMS alerts on all priorities of issues - even non-urgent ones that I don't need to wake me up in the middle of the night.

Is there a way on my iPhone to filter these texts based on words in the body or subject? I've got an iPhone 3GS, I think it's running iOS 4.x something but I can upgrade to iOS 5 if needed.

Comment: I'm not aware of any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You could send the SMSes through an online service like Google Voice that might be able to do content filtering (or at least would forward certain ones to email to filter).

Answer (score 0):

Unless disabled, the iOS Spotlight search and the in-app Messages search can find terms you might otherwise filter. Automating this in any way is strictly reliant on jailbreaking  the unit for a 3rd-party offering (of which I'm not aware).

Comment: well that sucks
darn it all ---

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GroupMe](http://groupme.com/) as a proxy Text service and set notifications to mute for that contact. That way you can take a look at the conversation if you want to, but don't get disturbed by it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in iOS unless you can have the messages sent from different addresses.  Then you could put the phone in Do Not Disturb mode, but allow the email address of the urgent contact to pass through by putting them in Favorites.

Alternatively, you could send the notifications to an email address and use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) or email filters to forward those with, for example, "urgent" in the subject to your cell phone's email address.